# Is this a standard way to maintain users' status (online/Offline)

Tags: node.js, laravel, sockets, socket.io, real-time

I have a real-time social networking web app written in Vuejs, Laravel and Nodejs.
I have queries to fetch online users like "`select * from users where is_online=1`"
Please don't suggest me not to keep this flag, I really need this flag.
To update this flag in the database I do the following

1. When user logs in a `socket.io` connection is established with a
   node app
2. In the `node/socket.io` app I update the `is_online` flag in the
   socket "`connection`" event as 1
3. When user logs off or browser closes or network connection
   disconnects, the "`disconnect`" is triggered here, again I update the
   "`is_online`" as 0

It works perfectly. However, when user refreshes the browser the connect and  disconnect event triggers on the server updating the database table twice.

**My question is**

1. Is this a standard way to determine users status in real-time?
2. What is the industry standards of doing such things?

I am aware of the last activity time-stamp thing but that is not my requirement.
Also I am aware of the technique to save ids in cache, but, again this is not my requirement. What I want is '**being able to query the database for online and offline users'**

Any kind of knowledge is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Couple things you can do to make it more flexible and scalable -

- Do not use online user status in database or RAM
- You can use storage like redis to do so
- Keep in mind what happens when 100K users are online

> There is no fixed standard way to do so but its almost the same way but more matured.

Involving database queries in frequent socket events are not performance friendly, however if you really want to save any details to db, you can do it.

I have worked on an application(which sometimes reaches to 40-50K online users) with same concept and it  works out really good.

Comment: In case of redis, as I explain, I wound be able to query the database for online users. Thoughts?

Comment: No, it works the other way and the easier way. For a simple example you can store an array of allOnlineUsersId and one one array userSocketIds to to store socketIds for each user. So you can get all users, socketId of a user or userId from a socketId in just once singleton operation, which is much better than querying the db, if think about having 10K users being online/offline every min.

Comment: The users are queried by parameters like "friend with current user", "gender" etc.

Comment: Can you give some example? @rahul

Comment: Right, so you will first collect the user and the required data from db and now you have all the ids so you can fetch their status from redis. So the goal is to avoid/remove frequent CRUD on db due to socket.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON file to store the user activity, and update the database table using the JSON file.

Create an active-users.JSON file write to that file whenever a new user logged in(socket connection established), logged out(socket connection disconnected) or even when a browser is reloaded JSON file is updated twice, and hence this will not create two unnecessary requests to the database.

Then you can use Laravel console command kernel to read the JSON file every 30 seconds or 1 minute, to read the data. If found any changes in data, update the database accordingly.

Comment: This leads frequent read/write to the file which, again fails the system @Jagadeesh

Comment: If you don't want frequent read/write to JSON file, you can create a global array and add/remove the users whenever new connection happens or browser closes or reloads. This way you always have connected users at any given time.